# How to re-rebase to other branch?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I'm working for some time with an - exclusively local - branch `dev` by standard rebasing on an organisations remote `master` branch:

```
    o-----o-----o  dev (local branch)
   /
--o-----o---  master 


                o'-----o'-----o' dev 
               /
--o-----o-----o--  master 

etc.
```

Not so currently, the organisation switched to another branch as basis for main development.

```
                  o'-----o'-----o' dev 
                 /
----o-----o-----o--  master 
     \
      o-----o-----o-----o-----o-- new_master
```

For reasons beyond the topic here, I was unable to sync my changes with the remote `master` before this happened and continued to surf on top of `master` locally, updating further from the remote master and rebasing on it with `dev`.

Now, before consuming my results, the organisation would like have my work rebased (in general and specific meaning) on `new_master`.

```
                  o'-----o'-----o'-- dev (former) 
                 /            | how/when?
----o-----o-----o-----o-----o-+---  master 
     \                        | how/when?
      o-----o-----o-----o-----o---- new_master
                               \
                                o''-----o''-- dev (new: maintain old dev commits)
```

My guess is, I have to wait for a merge between `master` and `new_master` (x) after the commit, I am currently based on with `dev` (a), before I can rebase again (after or at (x)) directly on `new_master`:

```
                  o'-----o'-----o' dev (former) 
                 /            
----o-----o-----a-----b-----c---  master 
     \                       \  merge?
      o-----o-----o-----o-----x-- new_master
                               \
                                o''-----o''-- dev
```

Is this correct, or I'm missing some unintended rewrite of history specifically of `new_master` when finally merging `dev` with it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `unintended rewrite`. When you rebase `dev` onto `new_master`, the very first thing git will do is finding the commits it actually has to rebase - which means the commits not present in the target branch (base for rebase). As you merge master into new_master, only the three commits you've shown will be reapplied. In no case existing `new_master` commits will be rewritten by rebase if you use it as is.

Comment: But it looks like you may bring along two commits from Master that were abandoned on new master. You may want to be very explicit about which commits you want to rebate and optionally first rebate your current branch on the source commit of new-master and then rebate onto new-master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done like this:

```
git rebase --onto new_master master dev
```

So.... take all `dev` revisions, discard revisions on `master`, put them on top of `new_master`

Comment: Does `--onto` take an `=` here? (It's not shown in the SYNOPSIS section, and not in the expansion under OPTIONS either, but it might well *work* as the Git options parsers tend to try to handle every possibility.) Anyway, other than maybe that, yes. :-)

Comment: Writing from memory.... it's probably not necessary. Sorry

Comment: Just figured out what happened with the `=`. My bash autocompletion provides the `--onto=` and that's why I use it. So I guess it's ok with or without `=`, as you said, @torek